# Regular expression that checks for 2 specific words

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that checks whether a string contains 2 specific words.

e.g. Whether the string contains `rooster` or `hen`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The expresssion to match `rooster` or `hen` as a complete word (i.e. not when they are part of a longer, different word):

```
\b(rooster|hen)\b
```

This is a safety measure to avoid false positives with partial matches.

The `\b` denotes [a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which is the (zero-width) spot between a character in the range of "word characters" (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and any other character. In effect the above would:

- match in `"A chicken is either a rooster or a hen."`
- *not* match in `"Chickens are either a roosters or hens."` - but `(rooster|hen)` would

As a side note, to allow the plural, this would do: `\b(roosters?|hens?)\b`

Answer (score 4):

Use `|` for alternatives.  In your case it's: `(rooster|hen)`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement but it should only contain a particular word (from a list) and no other words should be present in the string. I had to use `^(rooster|hen)$`

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention what engine/language you're using, but in general, the regular expression would be `(rooster|hen)`. `|` is the [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) operator.

Answer (score 1):

the thing that worked for me is

```
(?:word|anotheer word)
```

here an example of using I used it in my  application http://regexr.com/3gjb2

if you are interested in understanding how `(?:` is diff from `(` check this question

[What does (?: do in a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138161/what-does-do-in-a-regular-expression)